# Incompatible types - Found void java.util.Optional

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

There is a red underlined with the message:
`Incompatible types. Required: ...model.Constants Found: java.util.Optional` on jpa `findById` method.

I use `findById` is here:

```
Constants constants=constantsRepository.findById(1L);
```

And my model is:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "pkid")
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Any help please?

Here is my all code

**ConstantsRepository interface**

```
package com.destek.salaryCalculation.repository;

import com.destek.salaryCalculation.model.Constants;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ConstantsRepository extends  JpaRepository<Constants, Long>{

}
```

**BesCreateController java**

```
package com.destek.salaryCalculation.controller;

import com.destek.salaryCalculation.helper.BesCreateExcelHelper;
import com.destek.salaryCalculation.model.Personal;
import com.destek.salaryCalculation.repository.PersonalRepository;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping("/salarycalc")
public class BesCreateController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonalRepository personalRepository;

    @GetMapping("/besexcel/{group}")
    public void exportToExcelByGroup(HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable String group) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = "attachment; filename=bes.xlsx";
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        List<Personal> listPersonal = personalRepository.getListPersonelByGroup(group);
        System.out.println(listPersonal);
        BesCreateExcelHelper excelExporter = new 
       BesCreateExcelHelper(listPersonal);
       excelExporter.export(response);
    }
}
```

****And BesCreateHelper java****

```
package com.destek.salaryCalculation.helper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.destek.salaryCalculation.model.Constants;
import com.destek.salaryCalculation.model.Personal;
import com.destek.salaryCalculation.repository.ConstantsRepository;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class BesCreateExcelHelper {
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private XSSFSheet sheet;
    private List<Personal> listPersonalBes;

    @Autowired
    private ConstantsRepository constantsRepository;
    public BesCreateExcelHelper(List<Personal> listPersonalBes) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("bes.xlsx"));
        this.listPersonalBes = listPersonalBes;
        //workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        inputStream.close();
    }

    private void createCell(Row row, int columnCount, Object value, CellStyle style) {
        //sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnCount);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            cell.setCellValue((Boolean) value);
        }else {
            cell.setCellValue((String) value);
        }
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }

    private void writeDataLines() {
        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeight(15);
        style.setFont(font);

       Optional<Constants> constants2 = constantsRepository.findById(1L);
       Constants constants = constants2.orElseThrow(() ->new RuntimeException("No such data found"));;

        for (Personal personal : listPersonalBes) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
            int columnCount = 0;
            int i = 1;
            createCell(row, columnCount++, i++, style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, personal.getName(), style);
            createCell(row, columnCount++, personal.getIdentity().toString(), style);
            double besAmount=0;
            if(personal.getBes()==1){
                int numberDayOfMonth=constants.getDayOfWork();
           int sanitaryPermit=personal.getSanitaryPermit();
            double grossWages=0;
           if(sanitaryPermit<numberDayOfMonth) {
                grossWages = constants.getDailyWage() * (numberDayOfMonth - sanitaryPermit);
           }
               float socialHelp=constants.getSocialHelp();
               float mealBonus=constants.getMealBonus();
               float tisSupport=constants.getTisSupport();
               double deservedVehicleHelp=0;
               if(numberDayOfMonth>0){
                   int dayOfWork=numberDayOfMonth-sanitaryPermit-personal.getAnnualPermit();
                   // TODO: 11.01.2021 busTicketHelp tekrar hesaplatılacak.
                   double busTicketHelp=3.25*numberDayOfMonth;
                    deservedVehicleHelp=busTicketHelp*dayOfWork/numberDayOfMonth;
               }
               double mealPrice=(constants.getDayOfWork()-(personal.getSanitaryPermit()- Math.floor(personal.getSanitaryPermit()/7)*2)-personal.getAnnualPermit())*constants.getMealBonus();
               double extraWorkHourPrice=Math.ceil(personal.getExtraWorkHour()*constants.getDailyWage()/5);
               double extraWorkHourPriceSpecial=Math.ceil(personal.getExtraWorkHourSpecial()*constants.getDailyWage()/7.5*1.5);
               double mealException=constants.getMinimumWage()/30*6/100*mealPrice;
               double sgkPrimBaseAmount=grossWages+socialHelp+mealBonus+tisSupport+deservedVehicleHelp+mealPrice+extraWorkHourPrice+extraWorkHourPriceSpecial+mealException;
               besAmount=sgkPrimBaseAmount*0.03;
               }
            createCell(row, columnCount++, String.valueOf(besAmount), style);
        }
    }
    public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        //writeHeaderLine();
        writeDataLines();
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        // workbook.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: my constantsRepository extends JpaRepository

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `findById` returns an `Optional` ...

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear: findById method returns Optional. What is exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Since spring data jpa 2.0, the some methods was modified and return Optional instaed of the value, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316751/spring-data-jpa-findone-change-to-optional-how-to-use-this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @AnishB states you need to resolve the value from the optional but I would not use

```
... = constants.get();
```

straight away since this is dangerous `constants.get()` would throw `NoSuchElementException` if value does not exist

You should use:

```
Constants value = constants.orElse(null);
```

or even

```
Constants value = constants.orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException());
```

this line would throw exception but on that case you control the exception handling not something behind the scenes

BTW, You are getting a `NullPointerException` when try to call        `constantsRepository.findById(1L);` because the `BesCreateExcelHelper` is not a Spring dependency so you can not inject other spring dependencies into it at that case `constantsRepository` will be null

You have 2 options:

**#1**, Annotate that `BesCreateExcelHelper` with `@Component` annotation this will make `BesCreateExcelHelper` a spring dependency thus `constantsRepository` will be injected normally BUT you must convert `BesCreateExcelHelper` constructor into a method since constructors are used by Spring starting from version 4.3 to inject dependencies.

BesCreateExcelHelper would be like :

```
@Component
public class BesCreateExcelHelper {
...
public void init(List<Personal> listPersonalBes) { // notice this was the constructor logic
  .......
}
}
```

And then you inject `BesCreateExcelHelper` into the `BesCreateController`
and replace that `..new BesCreateController()` line with `besCreateExcelHelper.init(listPersonal)`

---

**#2** You can keep the `BesCreateExcelHelper` as it is but remove that Constant fetch line and pass the constant value from outside, ofcourse outside here means some other Spring component as you do in `exportToExcelByGroup` so simply you will execute `constantsRepository.findById(1L);` in the controller then pass it as a second constructor argument to the Helper class

...

```
constant = ...constantsRepository.findById(1L);
excelExporter = new 
       BesCreateExcelHelper(listPersonal, constant);
```

I like first option more

Comment: it did not work. I got java.lang.NullPointerException: null on the here          Optional<Constants> constants = constantsRepository.findById(1L);

Comment: i have record on my table with id=1

Comment: @hkngndz47 Assuming you are 100% sure there is a record in that DB and it is the one you are connected to, It should get you that record

Can you post the `ConstantRepository`  just to confirm there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: yes i am sure there is a record in my db that have id=1

Comment: Then please show the repo code and also the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Repository
public interface ConstantsRepository extends  JpaRepository<Constants, Long>{

}

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.destek.salaryCalculation.helper.BesCreateExcelHelper.writeDataLines(BesCreateExcelHelper.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.destek.salaryCalculation.helper.BesCreateExcelHelper.export(BesCreateExcelHelper.java:104) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.destek.salaryCalculation.controller.BesCreateController.exportToExcelByGroup(BesCreateController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: Null happens with line 62 in BesCreateExcelHelper.java, can you show that also

Comment: Optional<Constants> constants2 = constantsRepository.findById(1L);

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: Now as you can see the only object in that line is, `constantsRepository` that means there is something wrong with the injection
I saw your comments on @Anish so I'd suggest look on some different reasons you can find them at that post , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367316/spring-boot-autowired-does-not-work-classes-in-different-package

A strong reason might be that your repository is not scanned by Spring, means Spring does not consider it as a dependency so whenever you wire it, Spring will do nothing

Comment: Another reason that you may try to inject the repo into non-spring dependency, so at that case you must make sure `Optional<Constants> constants2 = constantsRepository.findById(1L);` is executed in a Spring dependency (@Service annotated class)

Comment: I can not really tell what exactly is the problem without seeing the code structure with a full vision

Comment: You can show the package structure via a screenshot image, and post the full Class in which you execute that line  `Optional<Constants> constants2 = constantsRepository.findById(1L);`

Comment: I added my code to my question. Can you look please?

Comment: @hkngndz47 Updated answer post please re-check

Comment: @hkngndz47 added more code sample to make it clearer

Comment: Not at all, Glad I can help!

Answer (score 2):

`findById(ID id)` method from `JpaRepository` returns a value of type `Optional<T>`.

To get the actual value from `Optional<T>`, you can use `get()` method but in some cases, data may not be there and you will get `NoSuchElementException`. So, you either return a default value with `orElse()` or you can throw an exception with `orElseThrow()`.

Example :

With `orElseThrow()` :

```
Optional<Constants> constants = constantsRepository.findById(1L);
                           
Constants value = constants.orElseThrow(() -> 
                                new RuntimeException("No such data found"));
```

With `orElse()`

```
Optional<Constants> constants = constantsRepository.findById(1L);
                           
Constants value = constants.orElse(null);

if(value == null) {
  // write some logic
}
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for answer but it did not work. I got java.lang.NullPointerException: null on the here          Optional<Constants> constants = constantsRepository.findById(1L);

Comment: i have record on my table with id=1

Comment: @hkngndz47 I got it. The bean for constantsRepository is not autowired. That's why you are getting nullpointerexception. constantsRepository is null.

Comment: it is autowired

Comment: @hkngndz47 Did you annotate the constantsRepository with `@Repository` ?

Comment: I added my code to my question. Can you look please?

Comment: @hkngndz47 remove the name from `@Repository` and try again.

Comment: @hkngndz47 Annotate helper with `@Component`. That's missing. You can't inject a bean in a non-registered bean.

Comment: It was already. I changed it to test it. so it gives same error with or without name

Comment: @hkngndz47 Put `@Component` on the BesCreateExcelHelper.

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.destek.salaryCalculation.helper.BesCreateExcelHelper.writeDataLines(BesCreateExcelHelper.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.destek.salaryCalculation.helper.BesCreateExcelHelper.export(BesCreateExcelHelper.java:98) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.destek.salaryCalculation.controller.BesCreateController.exportToExcelByGroup(BesCreateController.java:48) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: @hkngndz47 Provide your code base through github

Comment: @hkngndz47 Did you annotate helper class with `@Component` ?

Comment: @hkngndz47 Make the Helper class annotate with `@Component` and inject the helper class.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @hkngndz47 There is a problem of structure in helper class.

Comment: Thank you very much Anish B. I used @Component and injected helper class and also I converted Helper Constructor to a method like Youans said. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

findById return a Optinal data.You need to get it like this.

```
Optional<Constants> constants=constantsRepository.findById(1L);
```

Comment: @Repository ConstantsRepository extends JpaRepository< Constants, Long>