# Spring Boot autowires repositories but not services

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to use a file storage service in a REST controller. I am using the `StorageService` from [this Spring Boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/). This is the controller class:

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {
    @Autowired
    private StorageService storageService;
}
```

And this is the service class:

```
@Service
public interface StorageService {
    void init();
    void store(MultipartFile file);
    Path load(String filename);
    Resource loadAsResource(String filename);
    Stream<Path> loadAll();
    void deleteAll();
}
```

This empty controller class with the service autowired results in a runtime error:

```
Field storageService in com.wais.app.MessageApp.controllers.MessageController required a
bean of type 'com.wais.app.MessageApp.services.StorageService' that could not be found.
```

I've also come across this thread: [Spring Boot @autowired does not work, classes in different package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367316/spring-boot-autowired-does-not-work-classes-in-different-package), but in my case the main application class (which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) resides in package `com.wais.app.MessageApp`, the service resides in `com.wais.app.MessageApp.services` and the controller resides in `com.wais.app.MessageApp.controllers`. Moreover, I can successfully autowire repositories from package `com.wais.app.MessageApp.repositories` in the same controller.

What is going on here?

Comment: show the code of the broken service.  hint: does the service class have an @Service annotation?

Comment: Yes it has. I will paste the code in the question. It is also an interface, not a class.

Comment: You should annotate with @Service the implementation class (a bean), not the interface.

Comment: Thank you, I created a class and implemented this interface. It worked.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for feedback. I will add it as an answer.

Comment: "the error shows": `@Repository` implementations  are created "on the fly", while `@Service` Implementations are *not*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only classes annotated with @Component (@Service is a component too) will be initialize by Spring and made available for other classes as @Autowired. An interface has no "body" and no constructor. It can't be used by Spring this way.

**Solution**

Please implement the interface in a class and annotate the implementation class (a bean) with @Service, not the interface.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you should use constructor dependency injection like this
and remove the @AutoWired annotation as it is field injection and it is not recommended

```
@RestController
 public class MessageController {


private final StorageService storageService;
   
 public MessageController(StorageService storageService){

    this.storageService = storageService
  }
```

}

if you want to use @Autowired annotation then use it without private access modifier like this

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {
@Autowired
 StorageService storageService;

 }
```

Comment: I actually tried constructor injection also, and that was the error from constructor injection. Sorry for that, I will edit the question. I also tried removing the private modifier but the issue remains.